# RFID protocol simulator

Tags: authentication, protocols, simulator, rfid

I am developing authentication protocol between RFID reader and tag. But i couldn't find a simulator for that. I came across OMNET++ and NS2. But don't know how to do. How to use these simulators ? Is there any other simple simulator for RFID system? Please share your knowledge. Thanks.